# Why is "<br>" displaying instead of causing a break

Tags: javascript, html

This question has been asked, I apologize but I'm not seeing an answer to my question.  I am trying to display results to a text box and when I use "`<br>`" it is actually writing out br instead of creating a line break

I'm displaying  to a text box

here is the html for it

```
<input type ="text" name="display" id="display"  class="display" readonly>
```

This is the javascript I'm using

```
document.getElementById("display").value = "The highest test score is: " + max  + "<br>"+
   "The lowest test score is: " + min + "<br>" +
   "The average test score is: " + avg + "<br>" +
   "The scores are: " + results;
```

I've used this before but I've displayed to a `<p>` and it worked.
Is it something with the input type??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<input type="text" />` can only contain single line text, you should use a `textarea` element instead, which can contain multiple lines, like this :

```
<textarea>
this 
is 
some text
</textarea>
```

Note that setting `textarea.value` will work too.

Comment: this is probably the culprit.  I'll change up the html.

Comment: That was exactly the problem Thanks so much

Answer (score 3):

The value of a text box isn't interpreted as HTML.

A solution here is to use `\n`:

```
document.getElementById("display").value = "The highest test score is: " + max  + "\n"+
   "The lowest test score is: " + min + "\n" +
   "The average test score is: " + avg + "\n" +
   "The scores are: " + results;
```

But you probably should have a `textarea` here instead of an `input`, as you want to display several lines.

Comment: I have tried this.  It doesn't result in a new line, there seems to be no effect

Comment: It won't allow me to vote for both but this worked as well, I didn't see you mentioned the textarea until now

Answer (score 0):

Use textarea instead of input type="text" add "cols" and "rows" attribute on your own preference and then replace br tag with the "\n".

```
<textarea id="display" cols="15" rows="5" ></textarea>
```

```js
document.getElementById("display").value = "The highest test score is: " + max  + "\n"+
   "The lowest test score is: " + min + "\n" +
   "The average test score is: " + avg + "\n" +
   "The scores are: " + results;
```